# Value Error operands could not be broadcast together with shapes while using scaler.inverse_transform in Python

Tags: python, split, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, cross-validation

I am at the last part of my code and I am running into a operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (69331,4) (3,) (69331,4).

```
values = df.values 

## full data without resampling
#values = df.values

# integer encode direction
# ensure all data is float
#values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)

# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed.drop(reframed.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reframed.head())
```

Here is how I split my data:

```
# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_time = 29713
train = values[:n_train_time, :]
test = values[n_train_time:, :]
##test = values[n_train_time:n_test_time, :]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape) 
# We reshaped the input into the 3D format as expected by LSTMs, namely [samples, timesteps, features].
```

Here is how I made my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#    model.add(LSTM(70))
#    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Here is how I fit my network:

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=20, batch_size=70, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Here is how I make my predictions:

```
# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 4))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = np.concatenate((yhat, test_X[:,-3:]), axis=1)
```

Here is where my error occurs:

```
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
```

The error is:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (69331,4) (3,) (69331,4)`

If I do:

```
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
```

I get:

```
(29713, 1, 4) (29713,) (69331, 4) (69331, 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the shape of yhat?

Comment: inv_yhat is (69331, 4)

Comment: yhat is (69331, 1)

Comment: sorry, i meant to tag you @Denver

Comment: Where did you scale your data initially? It may be that when you scaled your data initially the shape was different than the shape you are attempting to inverse scale with now giving you the broadcast error.

Comment: I added it above. It is the first section of code.

Comment: What is the shape of `values`?

Comment: it is (99045, 3) before and after

Comment: Yeah the problem is that you transformed with shape (,3) and are attempting to to inverse transform with shape (,4). You need to either transform after you have re-shaped your data, or make sure your shape matches the original transform shape before applying the inverse transform.